# how to dynamically assign approver in workflow?

Tags: 2013, workflow, approval-process

We have a document library in which users upload document along with some meta data like doctype.

There is another list that has mapping of doctype and approvername.

There is a 2013 desigber work flow that runs on the doc library when a doc is added. I want this work flow to dynamically assign approval task to the approver based on the doctype value against the doc in the document library.